# without this and/or that

Tags: meaning, connotations

With negation, or is motly used.

> He doesn't like this or that.

But with without, I see both forms.

When I searched CCAE, it returned result with both or and and.

Like this:

> I was there without food and water.
>
> I was there without food or water.

I can see that both forms are used, but what's the difference between *without with and* and *without with or*? Is it that "food and water" is considered a thing in unity?

It was what most people said, but I don't think the texts with "and" actaully mean that. It is not even logical, is it? Water and food are separate. Even if you try to refer to them as a thing in unity, or as a one thing, can you possibly understand it that way?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on context, but both "and" or "or" can be used with "with" and "without".

> I was there with food and water.
>   *I was with both*
>
> I will be there with *(either)* food or water.
>   *I will be with one or the other*

If you said

> I was with food or water.

it would be confusing since it happened in the past and so the result should be known, if you added some context

> I was with food or water, I just can't remember right now.

it can make sense but still a struggle using "food" and "water" since one assumes you would remember something as simple as "food" or "water".

If you used "Jane" and "John"

> I was with Jane or John, I can't remember right now.

the example makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Bread and water is an idiom meaning figuratively 
**the most minimal meal possible**. (Originated from *a meal given to prisoners*).

> Wilbur knew that if he got in trouble again it would be at least a year on bread and water. This dinner is terrible again. I would rather have bread and water!

If you dont think of the noun phrase as a unity,you can use *or*.

> Perhaps I can do without one thing or the other.